# How to get Title Resource from a View with JSOM or REST?

Tags: rest, client-object-model, localization, resources

I am able to get title/name resource from lists, content types and fields. However, I'm not able to get title resource from views.

I'm not sure how well documented this is, but this is how I get resources from lists and fields:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById('');
var field = list.get_fields().getById('');
var listTitle = list.get_titleResource();
var fieldTitle = field.get_titleResource();
```

This is what I want to do:

```
var view = list.get_views().getById('');
var viewTitle = view.get_titleResource();
```

The methods to get title resource from lists and fields are documented, at least for [CSOM (List.TitleResource)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.titleresource(v=office.15).aspx).
However view does not seem to have any such method listed in [View memebers (CSOM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.view_members(v=office.15).aspx).
It does exist in [SSOM for SPView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.titleresource(v=office.15).aspx).